# How to use msdeploy and target a specific site?

Tags: msdeploy

When using msdeploy and the msdeploy.axd handler any attempts to deploy to my remote server is met with a 401 not authorized error and the server logs

> IISWMSVC_AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_NOT_ALLOWED
>
> Only Windows Administrators are allowed to connect using a server 
>   connection. Other users should use the 'Connect To Site or 
>   Application' task to be able to connect.
>
> Process:WMSvc

What is the correct way to target the axd for the site level?

Comment: How do you resolve this issue when you've done the steps below and still receive the error provided in the initial question?

Comment: @frogstarr78 I always install web deploy from the x64 binary, I've seemed to have had issues with web installer not doing something right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Web Deploy Tool 2.0 you can use IIS Manager UI to enable non-admin users to deploy website:

1. Start IIS Manager
2. Right-click the site you want to publish to, click Deploy and then click “Configure Web Deploy Publishing...”

[image: IIS Manager Web Deploy Publishing]

When you click Setup button Web Deploy grants necessary permissions to selected user. You can discard generated file.

See [Announcing Web Deploy 2.0 Refresh!](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2011/04/05/announcing-web-deploy-2-0-refresh.aspx)

Comment: Switched the answer to your response as this is a much more ready to go scenario.

Comment: What should the generated file be used for? Also, I'm still getting the problem even though I did this.

Comment: You can use generated file to set up publishing in WebMatrix.

Comment: @TomasJansson Please ask a new question for your problem.

Answer (score 10):

This might depend on how you're specifying the connection on the client side as well - if you're using msdeploy.exe you would specify the computername argument including a "?site=" query so that you connect at that site level rather than the server level, for example:

msdeploy.exe -verb:dump -source:iisapp="siteName",computername=https://servername:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=siteName,username=user,password=pass,authType=basic [-allowUntrusted]

Answer (score 5):

If you're using WMSvc, I'm assuming this is IIS7 ...

If so, then you can deploy with a normal account but you have to make sure these 3 criteria are met:

Your account needs to have:
1 IIS Manager permission for the site/app you are trying to connect with.
2 A delegation rule for msdeploy, that states that you are allowed to do *ContentPath* operations.
3 Actual filesystem/ACL access to the files.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer but since you took the time to answer my question I'll give you the bounty instead of letting it expire. I'll follow up if this solved my issue.

Comment: Could you please add some details about how to add a delegation rule?

Comment: A default set of delegation rules are now added during Web Deploy install (v2.1 and up). If you are creating delegation rules by hand there's an example/walkthrough here: http://blogs.iis.net/krolson/archive/2009/11/12/delegate-application-creation-for-non-admininistrator-accounts.aspx