# web deploy - IIS Manager User IISWMSVC_AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_NOT_ALLOWED

Tags: visual-studio-2015, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I have an azure VM with IIS and all the required firewall rules for web deploy setup. I can deploy my site if I use my windows admin account, but not with an IIS Manager user.

I think I've created all the necessarily requirements and can also remotely connect to the site at site level using IIS, but deploying fails with the following -

IISWMSVC_AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_NOT_ALLOWED

Only Windows Administrators are allowed to connect using a server connection. Other users should use the 'Connect To Site or Application' task to be able to connect.

Is there a setting I need to change when publishing via VS2015 to force it to connect to site level and not server level?

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention that I have also set the delegation permissions as described at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amol/2011/02/09/allowing-non-admin-users-to-deploy-web-applications-on-iis-7-using-web-deploy-2-0/

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23360094/1286665

In short, attach `?site=[YourSiteName]` to the MSDeployServiceURL.

I used the **Configure Web Deploy Publishing** wizard in IIS manager to create a .publishsettings-File. (Right click your site and choose *Deploy > Configure for Web Deploy Publishing...*) In that wizard I added `?site=[MySite]` to the *URL for the publishing server connection*. The wizard creates a file that can be imported in Visual Studio. (Right click your project, choose **Publish** and then **Import Profile**)

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx you could also provide the full URL to `msdeploy.axd?site=[YourSite]` in the *Service URL* field of the publishing wizard in Visual Studio when creating the profile manually.

Or you edit the content of the MSDeployServiceURL-Element in your .pubxml-File:

`<MSDeployServiceURL>https://contoso.com:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=[YourSite]</MSDeployServiceURL>`